# html5 form not submitting nor taking action to mysql table using php

Tags: php, html

php form not submitting or doing any action from the form to my database despite following all the rules for connecting the form to mysql with php

the php code supposed to get the infor from the form using the name tags but no action nor any error occurs when the data is submitted

HTML Form

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="register.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"  required="" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRight">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                <input id="phone" name="mobile" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRight">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="subject">Location</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon4"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></span>
                <input id="subject" name="location" type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="location">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Username</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                <input id="phone" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" required=""placeholder="username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRight">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="subject">Password</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon4"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></span>
                <input id="subject" name="password" type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInRight">
            <div class="input-group">
                 <label class="sr-only" for="subject">Interest</label>
                 <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon4"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></span>
                 <input id="subject" name="interest" type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="interest">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

PHP Form

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cusername = $_POST['username'];
$cpassword = $_POST['password'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,email,mobile,location,username,password,interest) 
    VALUES('$name','$email','$mobile','$location','$cusername','$cpassword','$interest')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username']=$cusername;
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
alert(\"Registration Complete , you will be redirected shortly\");
window.location = \"profile.php\"
</script>";
}
```

please advice what seems to be the problem that i am missing or not seeing

Comment: Is the HTML form a flat file, or generated? What is the path to access it? If `register.php` is in the root of your web directory, have you tried changing the action of the form to "/register.php"? You are currently using a relative path for action which could cause unexpected results depending on how everything is set up.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: html is a flate file and the name of the page is register.php that is why i added it to the action , i tried using post method only given that the php action is in the same page but it still did not work

Comment: @HossaTheCoder I think @trey was asking.. is `register.php` in the root folder along with the HTML form?

Comment: I tested it only stripping the mysql execution and putting all in the same register.php file and it worked fine for me.  Can you test this without doing the mysql call first and tell us if it works?  When you debug, it is best to do it step by step and isolate each step instead of testing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

try to connect with db first and pass the link into your query like this

```
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,email,mobile,location,username,password,interest) VALUES('$name','$email','$mobile','$location','$cusername','$cpassword','$interest')";
    // here put your LINK-CONNECTION
    mysql_query($sql,$link) or die(mysql_error());


    mysql_close($link);
```

and please filter the content you get from fields in your post, to avoid sql injection and other stuff.

Comment: `mysql_connect` - was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you all for your support , i simply missed the ID that the form had which was connected to a JS file for submitting the data and that was why the form was not seeing the php code

once removed everything was working fine

thank you all